# copy dynamic ranges from excel to word vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet of data and the range vary each week meaning last used row and last used column vary. I hope to copy 3 ranges at a time and paste it as picture into word using vba. This is part of a larger codes so that is why I am hoping to achieve it by writing vba.

The reason behind 3 ranges at a time is because of the picture size fits best in word. Headers are merged in row 2 and 3. I am showing you 4 ranges but sometimes I get 2 ranges and sometimes 6 ranges. i.e. 3 ranges or below should just be one picture and from 4-6 ranges will mean I have 2 pictures in word.

Right now when I run my codes, nothing is pasted in word.

```
Sub Table()

    Dim wdapp As Word.Application
    Set wdapp = New Word.Application

    With wdapp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        .Documents.Add
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table")
        Dim a, b, c, RR As Range
  '1
        Set a = .Cells.Find("Header1", LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not a Is Nothing Then
            Dim firstAddress As String
            firstAddress = a.Address
            Do
' 2
  Set b = .Cells.Find("Header1", a, LookIn:=xlValues)
' 3
  Set c = .Cells.Find("Header1", b, LookIn:=xlValues)
'Union
Set RR = Union(Range(a.End(xlDown).End(xlDown), a.Resize(, 7)), Range(b.End(xlDown).End(xlDown), b.Resize(, 7)), Range(c.End(xlDown).End(xlDown), a.Resize(, 20)))
    RR.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
                wdapp.Selection.Paste
                Set a = .UsedRange.FindNext(a)
                If a Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While a.Address <> firstAddress


        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

- Nested `With`s are normally a bad plan, and seem to be quite haphazard in this example
- `Find` doesn't like looking in rows that contain part of merged cells, so it's best to just use find on the whole sheet
- `.End(xlDown)` from a merged cell just selects the next used cell beolw it, not the whole block, so we need to apply this twice
- Your loop condition will produce an error if `d` is `Nothing`, as it still tries to check its address. Check for `Nothing` first and break out of the loop if needed

All told, this should work I believe:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Table()

    Dim wdapp As Word.Application
    Set wdapp = New Word.Application

    With wdapp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        .Documents.Add
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table")
        Dim d As Range
        Set d = .Cells.Find("Header1", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not d Is Nothing Then
            Dim firstAddress As String
            firstAddress = d.Address
            Do
                .Range(d, d.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
                wdapp.Selection.Paste
                Set d = .UsedRange.FindNext(d)
                If d Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While d.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

For the specific case of wanting to paste the first three blocks as one picture, and the fourth as a separate picture, you can replace the do loop with:

```
    .Range(d, d.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight)).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    wdapp.Selection.Paste
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
        Set d = .UsedRange.FindNext(d)
    Next i
    .Range(d, d.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    wdapp.Selection.Paste
```

Comment: Thanks for your input right now it copies each range as a picture, but how can I modify so I can get 3 ranges at a time?

Comment: Try playing around with the `Union` function. Now you have some working code to base it off, this should be doable. If you're still struggling after that, post your attempt at this part of the problem and we can have a look then.

Comment: Ok, I tried to define ranges using union but I don't think that is correct since I need to define how many ranges in order to set a, b, c and secondly, the results I have is a, b, c in one graph and b, c, d in another....but i want a, b, c as one, and d as second one. We can forgo the fact that d will be larger since its a solo one

Comment: I am getting run time error 91 now for my codes, object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: See the edit for how to do 3 together then the last one separately. You should be able to generalise this if necessary.

Comment: Thanks if I have 3 ranges, it's giving me an error 91...can this be avoided or modified so it can be used for any given ranges? Error occurred on second last line of the codes that need to replace the loop.

Comment: I'm sure it can be modified yes! At this point it's probably outside the scope of this question though. As i said, have a go and then, if you get stuck, post a new question with your specific query about this.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed your dim statements, since those will not work with 2016 on win 7

```
Dim wdapp As Object
Dim d As Range
Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

Then it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I still get an empty word document. And have you figured out how to grab 3 ranges at a time? I do not think my codes would perform that now.

Comment: I don't know how, since each copied range is its own picture.